# \parencites without repeating author's name

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,cmsdate=both,useprefix=false,ibidtracker=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{armstrong:universals,
author = {Armstrong, D.\ M.},
title = {Universals},
subtitle = {An Opinionated Introduction},
year = 1989,
location = {Boulder, CO},
publisher = {Westview Press},
}

@book{armstrong:truth_and_truthmakers,
author = {Armstrong, D.\ M.},
title = {Truth and Truthmakers},
year = 2004,
location = {cambridge, UK},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\parencites[94]{armstrong:universals}[see also][46--48]{armstrong:truth_and_truthmakers}

\end{document}
```

Which outputs the following:

[image]

Of course, the `\parencites` command is printing the author's name twice. Yet this is not how different publications from one author are usually referenced: the author's name should appear only in the first cited publication.

However, I can't simply use `\parencite` as I need to introduce the second reference through "see also". Nor I can use `\citeyear` for the second reference as I want the year to hyperref the entry in the reference list (which I have not included in the MWEB).

I'm sure there is a simple solution that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that the reason you cannot use `\citeyear` is that you want its hyperref to work, you could then use `\cite*` which will work as intended in your settings:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,cmsdate=both,useprefix=false,ibidtracker=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{armstrong:universals,
author = {Armstrong, D.\ M.},
title = {Universals},
subtitle = {An Opinionated Introduction},
year = 1989,
location = {Boulder, CO},
publisher = {Westview Press},
}

@book{armstrong:truth_and_truthmakers,
author = {Armstrong, D.\ M.},
title = {Truth and Truthmakers},
year = 2004,
location = {cambridge, UK},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\parencites[94]{armstrong:universals}[see also][46--48]{armstrong:truth_and_truthmakers}

(\cite[94]{armstrong:universals}; \cite*[see also][46--48]{armstrong:truth_and_truthmakers})

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: That should work, thanks. For some reason I thought there existed a specific command for that (at least in the `biblatex-chicago` package), as this is not an uncommon usage of citations. It appears there isn't.

Comment: I think what you have in mind is the behavior of `biblatex`'s standard `authoryear-comp`. I'm not sure `biblatex-chicago` has an option for that. But there might well be, someone may come up with another idea.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that

```
\parencites[94]{knuth:ct:a}[46--48]{knuth:ct:b}
```

gives you the output you expect, namely

> (Knuth 1984, 94; 1986, 46–48)

but that things go wrong with

```
\parencites[94]{knuth:ct:a}[see][46--48]{knuth:ct:b}
```

i.e. when you have a pre-note argument in the later citations. I guess the idea here is that the year (the citation label) of the second citation can get drowned out by the pre- and postnotes.

You can let `biblatex` drop the name even if a citation has pre-notes with

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,cmsdate=both,useprefix=false,ibidtracker=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:init}{%
  \ifnumless{\value{multicitecount}}{2}%
    {\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
     \global\undef\cbx@lasthash%
     \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
    {}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parencites[94]{knuth:ct:a}[46--48]{knuth:ct:b}

\parencites[94]{knuth:ct:a}[see][46--48]{knuth:ct:b}
\end{document}
```

[image: "(Knuth 1984, 94; 1986, 46–48)" and "(Knuth 1984, 94; see 1986, 46–48)"]

---

As it turns out a bit more has to be done if `\textcites` is used:

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite:authshort}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
    {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
      {\setunit{\multicitedelim}%
        \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}%
        {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}%
        {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}}}%
    {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
      {}%
    \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
      {\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}}%
  {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
        \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
        \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
        \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}%
        {\setunit{%
            \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
            \cms@testspace\bibopenparen}%
          \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
          {}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \ifboolexpr{%
            togl {cms@gencite}%
            and
            (
            test {\iffinalcitedelim}%
            or
            togl {cms@genallnames}%
            )
          }%
          {\thegen}%
          {}%
          \setunit{%
            \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
            \cms@testspace\bibopenparen}%
          \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
          {}%
          \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}}%
      {\printnames{labelname}%
        \ifboolexpr{%
          togl {cms@gencite}%
          and
          (
          test {\iffinalcitedelim}%
          or
          togl {cms@genallnames}%
          )
        }%
        {\thegen}%
        {}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \cms@testspace\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
        {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
        {}%
        \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}%
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
    {\printfield{shorthand}%
      \ifboolexpr{%
        togl {cms@gencite}%
        and
        (
        test {\iffinalcitedelim}%
        or
        togl {cms@genallnames}%
        )
      }%
      {\thegen}%
      {}%
      \setunit{%
        \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
        \cms@testspace\bibopenparen}%
      \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
      {}%
      \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
      {\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}%
      \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
    \stepcounter{textcitecount}}% Added ???
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}%
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
    {}%
    \textcitedelim}}% Not \multicitedelim ???
\makeatother
```